# Where are logon and startup scripts for graphical settings located and how are they managed?

Tags: login, scripts, startup, desktop-environments

Where and how are the Ubuntu equivalent of your personal Windows configuration stored? Something akin to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` as well as the Start Up menu.

I have spotted the *System* --> *Preferences* --> *Startup Applications* menu entry which seems to do some of it, but it doesn't appear to cover most of the things.

I am more concerned with those which a pertinent to a graphics login, either directly at the computer or remotely through `NX` or `x2go` for instance, as well as those that apply to every user such as this xrandr and those the user might configure personally

For instance I have got an `xrandr` script to set my screen resolution and I also need to configure Firefox to allow me to use multiple profiles. Currently I do all from the gnome terminal after logging onto the desktop.

Is there some guide where I can configure all these settings at logon time? The main thing is the should only apply to logging to Ubuntu or Gnome destkop, not logging on at the console.

Comment: If you create a .sh script with the stuff you need and tell Startup Applications to run it wouldn't solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programs that start at login in a graphical environment are called from .desktop launcher files in `~/.config/autostart` and in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`. [Here are the specifications for the autostart launchers.](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html) It's basically just a special case of the [normal .desktop specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/1.1/)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, individual applications store their data/configurations in `~/.[program]`, however, login programs store their initializations elsewhere.

For instance, to have something start upon terminal login, you could put it in `~/.bashrc`.

However, you want to have it start upon desktop login. For that, you should write a script that executes all the things you do by hand.

After that, set the script to executable (`chmod +x [script]`).

Last of all, go to `System --> Preferences --> Startup Applications`, and add your script to the list.

That should be it!

---

Comment if that doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer *per se* but just to add some more to what others said - depending on how well you know your system you might want to configure this with GUI. You will probably have to display all apps in `gnome-session-properties` first, i.e. ignore the *Hidden* attribute of *.desktop* files. To do so run `sudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/print-applet.desktop` and change `NoDisplay=true` to `NoDisplay=false`.

Other than that, each autostart `.desktop` file can contain `OnlyShowIn` entry, e.g. `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;` will only run an app in GNOME and not in Unity, LXDE or other environments.